# What is the effect on the Fourier transform of an image if I increase/decrease its size?

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing, fft

Would there be a difference between the Fourier transform of an image and an equivalent image of larger/smaller size?

I'm using Matlab to classify images and thought I could increase the accuracy of the classifier by re-sizing all the images to the same size (using imresize). Is this an unnecessary step (if the Fourier transform is equivalent)? Or could it make the Fourier transforms of the images more consistent and thus easier to classify?

Comment: Yes. Also depends on how the sizes were manufactured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends on the content of the image. If you can still see the information that you think is important, then the FFT of that smaller image will still be useful in that same sense. Resampling an existing image at lower resolution simply removes high spatial frequency content (fast changes, say like the pattern of a newspaper print) at the same proportion as you undersample, so if you don't need those high frequencies, you are fine.